# using $i var into sql query with php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to execute this sql query using PHP

```
$sql="SELECT convert (varchar(500),Xml.query('for $i in /data/var1/text()   return concat($i, "||")')) as var1 FROM #table1";

echo $sql;              

$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
```

i have a problem with $i, the variable is used in the loop in the sql query .

I tried to put it between singles quotes and doubles quotes, i also tried this : \'$i\' but it's not working.

Comment: If `$i` is meant to be used by the sql query and not coming from a PHP variable, try adding a slash before the dollar sign. `...for \$i in...`

Comment: yes it s coming from the sql query but the odbc_exec doesnt reconize my query with the \$i

Comment: You may need to try running the query directly into the database and see what happens. I also see you'll need to escape both the dollar sign and double quotes in `concat($i, "||")`

Comment: the query is working on sql server but not in php

Comment: Try `echo $sql;` to see how it differs from what you expect. That will show you where the issue lies.

Comment: i have this msg when i m doing echo $sql Notice: Undefined variable: i in

Comment: Make sure you have all of the dollar signs escaped. You have 2, so add a slash before both of those.

Comment: yes i escaped the both the the echo is printing "1" when i espace both

Comment: Can you show your query with the escaping characters now?

Answer (score 0):

If you $i is php variable, than you have to inject it like in code below:

```
$sql="SELECT convert (varchar(500),Xml.query('for ".$i." in /data/var1/text()   return concat(".$i.", \"||\")')) as var1 FROM #table1";
```

I also escaped double quotes that you used in concat() function, they surely wouldn't work as you wrote it, but I'm not 100% sure if that way of escaping them gonna work - personally I'm avoiding similar situations.